# Create route that will move the query string to part of the url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'd like to change my routes so that instead of having:

```
/Users/Edit?UserID=1
```

I can do

```
/Users/Edit/1
```

How can I create a custom route to do that?

Also, can someone direct me to a good tutorial on routes? I don't wanna create a post every time I have a simple problem with routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually http://localhost/Users/Edit/1 can do the what you want without defining a new route. The default route structure is http://localhost/controllerName/actionMethodName/id.

So if you just use "id" instead of "UserID" in your action method. The number in the URL would be assigned to the parameter on action.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

Here's a few lesson on routing. Take a look at them. It's a quite easy thing to understand.

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs
- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-routes-cs
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the htaccess file.  You put in a regular expression which will extract pieces of the file path as if it is part of the query string.

[This is a link I googled](http://www.tamingthebeast.net/articles3/spiders-301-redirect.htm) it may do the trick.

Comment: Since he is using ASP.NET MVC, he is probably not using Apache and doesn't have htaccess files.

Comment: Yeah, something similar though... IIS has to have a similar type file... I just don't know what it is called.  Googling htaccess .net is bound to give him the right answers.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do something like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "MyRoute",
            "{controller}/{action}/{UserId}",
            new { controller = "DefaultController", 
                                  action = "DefaultAction", 
                                  UserId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```